# Template tag variables at django are not displayed

Tags: django

I’m building a blog and I’m new to django. I’m trying to build a post display page but tag variables are not working.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
.
.
.

    path('post/<slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
.
.
.
def post_detail(request, slug):
    all_posts= Post.objects.all()
    this_post = Post.objects.filter(post_slug=slug)
    return render(request = request, 
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html', 
    context = {'this_post':this_post, 'all_posts':all_posts})
.
.
.
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'blog/header.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="s12">
      <div class="card grey lighten-5 hoverable">
        <div class="card-content teal-text">
            <span class="card-title">{{  this_post.post_title  }}</span>
            <p style="font-size:70%">Published {{  this_post.post_published  }}</p>
            <p>{{  this_post.post_content  }}</p>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks from  now!

Comment: please post your model also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of filtering, need to bring out single object then only it will be available in detail view. Output of filer will be a list.

```
this_post = Post.objects.get(post_slug=slug)
```

or

```
this_post = get_object_or_404(Post, post_slug=slug)
```

Answer (score 0):

`this_post` is not a Model instance - it's a Queryset. `Post.objects.filter()` always returns a Queryset, even if there's only one record. Attribute `post_title` is an attribute of Post instance - not of a queryset.

You can do either:

1. use `get()`:

```py
Post.objects.get(post_slug=slug)
```

2. ...or add `first()` to the queryset:

```py
Post.objects.filter(post_slug=slug).first()
```

What's the difference?

1. `get()` will return an instance or raise `Post.DoesNotExist` exception if Post is not found.
2. `filter(...).first()` will return first result from queryset (as model instance) or `None`, if nothing was found.